# How to use clustering with unique constraints in postgres?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

How can we add clustered/nonclustered indexing to unique constraints in postgres, equivalent script in SQL Server is below, how can we achieve it postgres

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
col1 int,
col2 int,
col3 int,
CONSTRAINT UK_tbl1 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
col1 ASC,
col2 ASC
))
```

Any help for indexing unique constrained columns will be appreciated.

Comment: Ask for storage parameters in [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). I'm voting to migrate the question.

Comment: Postgres does not have clustered indexes. So just create a regular unique index (or unique constraint).

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto I just edited question, that was not required for postgres, needed help with clustering

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for reply, so I am assuming creating unique constraint would automatically create indexing and that is all we can do.

Comment: See the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html):

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree
>   index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint.

Comment: Thanks for reply, ok you mean indexing is not necessary but how can achieve clustering?

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has no concept of a "clustered index" as MS-SQL uses the term. My understanding is that in MS-SQL a "clustered index" makes the table an *index-oriented table*, where the whole table is b-tree structured. PostgreSQL cannot do this.

It can do *index-only scans*, which work a bit like scans of a *covering index*.

It also has the `CLUSTER` command, which does a one-off sort and rewrite of a table in the order of an index. But it doesn't *maintain* that ordering.

Unlike MS-SQL's clustered indexes, though, it can't avoid storing the table heap, and it can't maintain the table in a b-tree.